# Accessing an email attachment as an object

Tags: vbscript, outlook, email-attachments

OK so I have a script that goes through my outlook inbox looking for a particular header string. This works great for emails directly in my inbox. Now I'm trying to expand this detection to emails that contain other emails as attachments. I've spent significant time researching this and I can't seem to find the proper way to access the email attachment directly. What I've ended up doing is saving the attachment to disc and then reading it back in using CreateItemFromTemplate. I find this to be a cludge solution and I'm hoping someone here can help me find a more elegant way to do this where I can bypass the saveas as CreateItemFromTemplate and directly create an item object from the attachment. Here is proof of concept script I've put together for this:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Const olMail = 43
Const olEmbeddeditem = 5
Const PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"

Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set objNamespace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
set objInboxItems = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items
wscript.echo "Have your inbox open checking for fish tests or emails as attachments"
for each objItem in objInboxItems
    if objItem.Class = olMail then
        with objItem
            strHeader = .PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PropName)
            iLoc1 = instr(1,strHeader,"X-Testing",1)
            if iLoc1 > 0 then
                wscript.echo "mytest. From: " & .Sender & " at: " & .ReceivedTime & " subjet: " & .Subject
            end if
            iLoc1 = instr(1,strHeader,"X-PHISHTEST",1)
            if iLoc1 > 0 then
                wscript.echo "Go Fish. From: " & .Sender & " at: " & .ReceivedTime & " subjet: " & .Subject
            end if
            if .attachments.count > 0 then
                set objAttachment = .attachments.item(1)
                if objAttachment.type = olEmbeddeditem then
                    wscript.echo "Has Attachment. From: " & .Sender & " at: " & .ReceivedTime & " subjet: " & .Subject
                    wscript.echo " - Filename: " & objAttachment.Filename
                    objAttachment.SaveAsFile ("c:\temp\TempEmail.msg")
                    set objExtMsg = app.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\temp\TempEmail.msg")
                    strExtHeader = objExtMsg.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PropName)
                    iLoc1 = instr(1,strExtHeader,"X-Testing",1)
                    if iLoc1 > 0 then wscript.echo " ++ This is a plain test message"
                end if
            end if
        end with
    end if
next
wscript.echo "That's all folks"    `
```

Comment: *An Attachment object can be rendered into HTML hypertext using the CDO Rendering ObjectRenderer object. To specify this, set the object renderer's DataSource property to the Attachment object itself. The individual properties that can be rendered with the RenderProperty method are indicated in the Attachment object property descriptions.* from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526700(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: I specifically do not want the object rendered, it will actually have negative effect on my POC if message is rendered. I'm looking to access the email headers and check if a particular header exists, either in the message it self or in an attached email.

Comment: Did you read it. It gives access to the data for YOU to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the best you can do in OOM alone - save the attachment as an MSG file and then reopen it. `OpenSharedItem` is a better way to open an MSG file than `CreateItemFromTemplate`.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you can open the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property as `IMessage` using [IAttach::OpenProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839910.aspx). If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language) - both [Safe*Item](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safeobjects.htm) and [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) families of objects expose EmbeddedMsg property on the [attachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) object that return the attachment message.